# Flash Not Navigating In Same Window

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

The following is not navigating within the same window as defined by _self it is opening a new window. No clue as this has worked before for me. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest('./homepage.php'),'_self');
});
```

Comment: are you trying it out on your local machine? is the html file in the trusded direcrtories list of flash player?

Comment: sorry trusted directory, it happens on the computer and in the website.

Comment: Have you tried it without the `./` in the URL?

Comment: do you have a debugger flash player? if no, please install it. might be then you will see a bug or something.

Comment: And this is why we do not use inline functions in an OOP language. It makes it difficult to debug

Answer (score 0):

You need to test it on server to work properly.